# Blazorred - async getters/setters: How do I get a session variable inside a timer loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, blazor

i have a problem with getting / calling an async getter function within a timer-loop.. i tried to call the relevant line within a method and it gets accepted/no syntax error, but as soon as i write it within the timer-environment i get an error. Details as follows:

1. Within my select-callback function, i set a sessionvariable using the Blazorred - library:

   **`await myLocalStore.SetItemAsync("ActiveChannel", i_active_channel);`**
2. In the background, there's an autorefresh function running, which should continously refresh my session variables within an endless- timer - loop:

   ```
        Globals.timerCameras = new Timer(new TimerCallback(_ =>
        {
          //here, i want to get my session variable / updates of my session variable every 
          // 500ms
          //WRONG SYNTAX: 
          my_active_measurement_channel = await myLocalStore.GetItemAsync<string>("ActiveChannel");
        }), null, 1000, 500);
   ```
3. I get the following Error message:

**The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async' - modifier.**

I also tried calling the method with different syntaxes, like using the "Task.Run" - style of writing, but "GetItemAsync" is from Type "ValueTask" and ValueTask does not inherit the function "Run" so this way it does not work, and now i am at a point where i just randomly try things and i do not really understand the underlying problem with writing the usual getter-line:

```
my_active_measurement_channel = await myLocalStore.GetItemAsync<string>("ActiveChannel");
```

Would be really cool if someone could help me understanding this problem here, i am rather confused at the moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's the best solution, but you can use `await` by simply adding `async` to your TimerCallback lambda:

```
Globals.timerCameras = new Timer(new TimerCallback(async _ =>
{
    my_active_measurement_channel = await myLocalStore.GetItemAsync<string>("ActiveChannel");
}), null, 1000, 500);
```

Comment: Pleas note that this eventhandler is now an `async void`, with all the problems that could bring.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Aren't most (if not all) of those problems related to *writing* an async null method. In this case the OP is not writing a method that will be consumed by other developers.

Comment: I'm not saying it won't work but you will have to `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` yourself. And handle all exceptions on the spot.